# Detect heap corruption BEFORE garbage collect

Tags: c#, heap-corruption

I am using CDB (Microsoft Console Debugger,) and [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) to try to force a break when heap corruption occurs by [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) into ReadFile. I read many more bytes from a text file than what I've allocated to the chBuf array. The debugger does not see the access violation until after `GC.Collect`, which is **too late** for me. Prior to running my program, I run

```
gflags -p /enable testheap.exe /unaligned
```

The effect seems useless. I wrote this little test program to apply what I find to debugging a much larger commercial program that is having heap corruption issues.

I have also tried DebugDiag with [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and MDA callbackOnCollectedDelegate without success. Isn't my use of `gflags` supposed to detect heap corruption immediately after ReadFile?

The code:

```
    namespace TestHeap

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
            uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
            uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ReadFile(SafeFileHandle hFile, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
            uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

        string fileName = "testHeap.txt";
        const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
        const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
        SafeFileHandle sh;
        byte[] chBuf = new byte[8];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void testBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool nStat;
            uint bytesToRead = 1025;
            uint bytesRead = 0;

            if (!(nStat = ReadFile( sh, chBuf, bytesToRead, out bytesRead, IntPtr.Zero)))
                Debug.Print("testBtn_Click error in ReadFile, nStat = {0}", nStat);
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("After ReadFile, bytesToRead = {0},\n bytes read = {1}", bytesToRead, bytesRead));
            GC.Collect();
            MessageBox.Show("testBtn_Click end, after GC.Collect");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sh = CreateFile(fileName, GENERIC_READ, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the debugger does not see the access violation until after `GC.Collect`." That is the point the access violation is raised. How can the debugger see an access violation *before it occurs*? If you mean that the corruption is not detected until the `GC.Collect`, then you just need to look for the corruption sooner, like by calling `HeapValidate` explicitly.

Comment: Raymond, the access violation occurs before GC.Collect.  If I break and !verifyheap before GC, it shows the managed heap is already corrupt. Setting gflags is supposed to catch that. See microsoft support Article ID: 286470. It just doesn't work for me as advertised. In my commercial program, GC can occur long after the heap corruption. Shouldn't an exception be thrown at the time the heap is corrupted?  Why doesn't the debugger catch it then?

Comment: Also, the Win32 HeapValidate does not seem useful for checking managed heap problems. How would you provide the correct arguments for using that?

Comment: `HeapValidate` only validates heaps created via `HeapCreate`. The unmanaged heap was not created that way, so you'll have to find a corresponding validation function for the unmanaged side. (It wasn't clear from the problem statement whether the corruption was in the managed or unmanaged heap, though I should've thought about it a bit more.) I don't know if there is a corresponding "please scan the managed heap for corruption" function.

Comment: gflags and pageheap are for debugging heaps created via `HeapCreate`. They do not have any knowledge of custom heaps, like the unmangaed heap.

Comment: Use the SOS VerifyHeap command.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but I believe the unexpected gflags behaviour is caused by this line:

`byte[] chBuf = new byte[8];`

Since `chBuf` is managed by the CLR, gflags is not able to put the fill pattern after it to detect buffer overruns. Try changing that to:

`IntPtr chBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8);`

So that you will be allocating in the unmanaged heap. Gflags should be able to work with that. Also, you may need to change the signature of `ReadFile` for that to work:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadFile(SafeFileHandle hFile, [Out] IntPtr lpBuffer,
uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

Comment: Ilian, thanks for your suggestion. I tried this and no exceptions are ever thrown. If there will be a buffer overrun on the native heap, ReadFile simply returns 0 bytes read.  However, being that my large commercial code is completely in C# this approach will probably miss many managed to native pinvokes in my code - for example, within third party controls, setting up USB communications, not to mention transitions within Microsoft code.

Comment: The P/Invoked `ReadFile` is probably swallowing the debug break thrown from the native side. Try running your sample project under a debugger to check if it can detect the buffer overrun while `ReadFile` is being invoked... Just checked this approach on my machine and it works. Although, I don't know if this is feasible with your larger project.

Comment: Ilian, please provide more details on how this worked for you. Did you run the sample project above? I tried your suggestion running the debug and release config in Visual Studio 2005. Enabled project unmanaged debugging. Debug/Exceptions menu item: set break when "Win32 access violation" and CLR/System.AccessViolationException. I request 513 characters from a text file, with a chBuf of size 8. The ReadFile reports 513 characters read and continues. When GC.Collect instruction is attempted the program freezes. Thanks.